# Ansible vault - best practice folder structure

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to figure out the best practice folder structure to organize my vault variables.

Currently it looks like this:

```
.
├── group_vars/
│   ├── group1.yml
│   └── group2.yml
├── host_vars/
│   ├── host1.yml
│   └── host2.yml
├── roles/
│   └── .../
└── vault/
    ├── enc-file1.yml
    └── enc-file2.yml
```

However, this way I always have to use `include_vars` inside my role to *source* a specific encrypted file.

Is there any naming convention and folder structure I can apply that Ansible will automatically *source* the correct vaulted variable just as it does with `host_vars` and `group_vars`?

I had something like this in mind:

```
.
└── group_vars/
    ├── group1/
    │   ├── main.yml
    │   └── vault.yml
    └── group2/
        ├── main.yml
        └── vault.yml
```

Is there anything I can do, so I do not have to explicitly include vault variables?

Comment: Best practices about vault variables: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#variables-and-vaults

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything I can do, so I do not have to explicitly include vault variables?

In recent Ansible versions (since 2.3) you don't need to include separate files for vault-protected variables. Instead, you can encrypt individual variables in regular vars-files - see [Single Encrypted Variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#single-encrypted-variable).

> Is there any naming convention and folder structure [] that Ansible will automatically source the correct vaulted variable []?

No, there is no convention nor automatic mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this. Btw, how would I work on these files? How can I encrypt/decrypt a single variable within this file?

Comment: Click on the link I included in the answer and read. The question is about best practices/general mechanism, not about command details, so I see no reason to copy-paste from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

@cytopia, what you have in mind works.

You can split encrypted/clear inventory variables in separate files. Ansible will sort out what is crypted and what is not.

I use the following layout and had no problems with it so far (1.9.x - 2.2.1.0):

```
group_vars/
    all/
        clear
        secret
    group1/
        clear
        secret
    group2/
        clear
        secret
```